# Replace a string with another in request.rawurl not working

Tags: c#-2.0, str-replace

I want to replace some string in my url like this

```
request.RawUrl.ToString().Replace("sometext566666", "othertest")
```

but it s not working why is it so?

For example, the original url is like

```
/sometext4554544454.aspx
```

and I want it like this

```
/sometext.aspx
```

Comment: At a guess, this is either C# or VB.Net. But we shouldn't *have* to guess. Please add an appropriate language tag to your question.

Comment: `String.Replace()` it works, but the problem is that you probably did not redirect to new Url

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is .NET. If so, you should be aware the `String.Replace()` returns a *new* string containing the result of the replacement (as do all other methods that purport to modify a string).

So you need to assign the result to a variable or field to hold the result. In some circumstances, you might assign the result back to the same place you obtained the original string from. But you're not allowed to overwrite `RawUrl` (and, it would be potentially confusing for you to do so).

Comment: sorry for not mentioning the language. It is c#. this is wrong url /sometext4554544454.aspx so i want to redirect that wrong URL to correct one by replacing that unwanted characters. I am in a confusion that why string.replace not working for this request.rawurl.tostring(). this is my code to do that. res.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";string sURL=req.RawUrl.ToString();
                        string newURL=sURL.Replace(stateName, dr["statename"].ToString().ToLower());res.AddHeader("Location", newURL);
                        res.Flush();
                        res.End();

Comment: @SivaMyneni - you can edit your question (there's a link at the bottom, under the tags) to clarify things or to add tags. I'd suggest you add (at least) the c# tag.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are using is working, but you are not assigning the result of the replace function, just executing it.

```
request.RawUrl.ToString().Replace("sometext566666", "othertest")
```

If you want to keep the result, you will need to assign it to a string.

e.g.

```
String result = request.RawUrl.ToString().Replace("sometext566666", "othertest");
```

Otherwise, you can assign it to the same RawURL but I think that is a URI so you'll need to use a new URI, something like:

```
request.RawUrl = new URI(request.RawUrl.ToString().Replace("sometext566666", "othertest"));
```

Nevertheless, I'm not sure if you can actually edit that property.